# How do I add the "containers" package to my .cabal file (without getting overwritten by stack at compile time)?

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

I am working on the "roman-numerals" task from the exercism Haskell track and followed their [instructions to installing stack](http://exercism.io/languages/haskell/installing). I am working on a Fedora 24 box.

As long as I was working with Haskell modules from base, I didn't have a problem. Now I am trying to import the Data.Map module. It works fine using the ghci command line:

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 7.8.4: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Prelude> import Data.Map
Prelude Data.Map>
```

However, when I try to import it from inside my src file with the command:

```
import qualified Data.Map as M (foldlWithKey, fromList)
```

I am running into problems when I try to run the test:

```
$ stack test
roman-numerals-0.0.0: build (lib + test)
Preprocessing library roman-numerals-0.0.0...
[2 of 2] Compiling Roman            (...)
(...) /roman-numerals/src/Roman.hs:3:1: error:
    Failed to load interface for ‘Data.Map’
    It is a member of the hidden package ‘containers-0.5.7.1’.
    Perhaps you need to add ‘containers’ to the build-depends in your .cabal file.
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
Progress: 1/2
(...)
```

I googled the problem and found a straightforward solution at [the Cabal FAQ at haskell.org](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/FAQ.html#hidden-packages-a):

> What you need to do is to add containers to the build-depends in your .cabal file.

I am assuming they mean the file roman-numerals.cabal that is in my working directory. The contents are:

```
-- This file has been generated from package.yaml by hpack version 0.14.0.
--
-- see: https://github.com/sol/hpack

name:           roman-numerals
version:        0.0.0
build-type:     Simple
cabal-version:  >= 1.10

library
  hs-source-dirs:
      src
  build-depends:
      base
  exposed-modules:
      Roman
  other-modules:
      Paths_roman_numerals
  default-language: Haskell2010

test-suite test
  type: exitcode-stdio-1.0
  main-is: Tests.hs
  hs-source-dirs:
      test
  build-depends:
      base
    , roman-numerals
    , hspec
  default-language: Haskell2010
```

I tried to add "containers" to the build-depends in either and both the "library" and "test-suite" sections, but when I run

```
$ stack test
```

the error persists, and the .cabal file is reverted to the same contents shown above.

Any pointers? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is hinting at the problem:

```
-- This file has been generated from package.yaml by hpack version 0.14.0.
--
-- see: https://github.com/sol/hpack
```

[hpack](https://github.com/sol/hpack) is an alternative, YAML-based specification format for Haskell packages which can be used instead of the traditional cabal format. The `hpack` program can then be used to convert a specification from the hpack format to the cabal format to be able to integrate with the rest of the Haskell toolchain.

Some [basic support for hpack](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/pull/1773) was added to stack some time ago. It checks for a file called `package.yaml` in the current directory, which is the standard name for hpack format package specifications, and if it exists, it runs `hpack` to convert it to a cabal file and then proceeds building as normal. This is what's trampling over your .cabal file.

To solve this, either:

- Modify `package.yaml` instead of `roman-numerals.cabal` to achieve the same effect.
- Delete `package.yaml` and continue working directly with `roman-numerals.cabal`.

The syntax for adding dependencies in the hpack format is:

```
dependencies:
  - base
  - containers
```